# Sonar REST API to change the snapshot's version

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

SonarQube allows us to changes/create versions for snapshots from the History tab of the project Adminstration. I would like to know if there is a REST API or any other way I can update/create the same from commandline/Jenkins.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a link to your server's on-board web services documentation in the footer.

Comment: Thanks Ann. But in my servers web services I dont see any API to edit/update the version in the event snapshot. Can you please help me on the same.

Comment: What version is your server?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam : Thanks. The version is 5.6.3

Answer (score 0):

In SonarQube 5.6, you can use :

- POST api/events to create an event
- DELETE api/events to delete an event

More information are available in the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392183).

Please note that starting SonarQube 6.3, api/events will not be available anymore and is replaced by [api/project_analyses](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/project_analyses)